# What's with this mysterious left margin on my site? Why isn't it flush with the left edge of my browser?

Tags: javascript, css, html

http://willryan.us

If you resize your browser you'll see that the left side of the page stays a little bit off the edge, but the right side doesn't. I don't think I have a margin-left on anything, and that's the only thing I could think of that could be causing this. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! It's best if you narrow down the problem first, and post a short and working code sample of the problem here. That way this question may still be of use to future users (which is the point of SO). Note that you can edit your question at any time!

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the presence of the left margin looks natural because of the drop shadow that your page has. If you want it gone though, that's not my decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<body>` has no padding or margin specified, so it's defaulting to whatever the browser default is. In Chrome, for example, the margin is  `8px`.

[image]

Set a margin and padding to `0` and the left side of your layout becomes flush with the left edge of the browser window.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: beat me to it :/, but yours is better

Comment: Thanks, that half-fixed it! But now some divs that had specified margins (like the header/nav bar), got overwritten by adding that code. Do I now add an important tag wherever I want the margin values to change?

Comment: This is why it's good to use a **[css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)** when starting a project. You'd have inadvertently prevented these side effects long ago by being forced to specify the margins/paddings you need for the elements newly showing problems.

Comment: **To be clear:** If you specified a margin/padding for some `<div id="header">`, it will **not** get overwritten by the above code.

Comment: I recommend the use of [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/), not reset. With reset, you will have to specify all the styles, margins and paddings for the elements who need them.

Comment: Do have an example of an overwritten element (that is live)? Specified margins do not get overridden by inherited styles (I don't think padding and margin are even inherited either). I think the order of precendence is: !important, styles in element tag, IDs, pseodo-classes, attribute selectors, classes, tag, inheritance (from  most important to least).

Comment: Ahhh damn... I was worried it would end up getting complicated. I might try messing around with normalize.css, but it seems a little over my head.

Answer (score 1):

The `html` and `body` elements by default have padding/margin, the amount of which varies by browsers. If you don't want it simply add this to your css:

```
html, body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
```

You can inspect elements in both Chrome and Firefox (if you have Firebug), and both will display the layout information of the element.